# Making .htaccess more efficient

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess that I've cobbled together over the years using this site as a guide but hoping I can consolidate some of the lines to make it more efficient.

These lines do three things:

1. Redirect any non-www requests to the www variant;
2. Redirect any .com requests to the proper .org TLD;
3. Redirect any http to the proper https variant; 3.

Here's what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R,L]
```

Is there a way to combine (at least some) of these functions into fewer lines?

I'm NOT having any problems, it's just the organizer in me that feels it could be neater.....

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Remove excessive `RewriteEngine On` and then it would look great: the rules are explicit and clear. Even if it was possible (or easy to do so) - then the result would be x10 times messier.

Comment: @zerkms It would seem "looks" are deceiving!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> # Rule #1
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
>
> # Rule #2
> RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com
> RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
>
> # Rule #3
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.org [NC]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R,L]
> ```

Yes, your rules can be optimised. Not least because they don't actually do what you say they do!

(I'm assuming you have no intention to implement [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)?)

> 2. Redirect any .com requests to the proper .org TLD;

These directives don't actually redirect the `.com` variant to `.org`, as you suggest in your 2nd requirement. If you are seeing this redirect then it's not because of these directives. Most probably WordPress itself is doing this, later in the request.

For example...

Scenario #1:

- Request `http://www.example.com/` (or `https://www.example.com/`)
- No redirects occur since the requested host does not match **rule #1**, **#2** or **#3**
- The request is not redirected to `.org` (or HTTPS in the case of a request to `http://...`)

scenario #2:

- Request `http://example.com/` (or `https://example.com/`)
- Redirect to `https://www.example.com/` (same domain) by **rule #1**
- No further redirects occur as stated in "Scenario #1" above.
- The request is not redirected to `.org`.

As you can see from these examples your **rule #2** (that matches `example.com` only) doesn't actually do anything. It is always *bypassed* because **rule #1** has already redirected the request to the `www` subdomain. It would be "better" if **rule #1** and **#2** were reversed, however, that still wouldn't resolve the issue when `www.example.com` (www subdomain) was requested, as nothing would happen still.

Other notes:

- **Rule #3** - HTTP to HTTPS redirect - is a temporary (302) redirect. This should be a 301, like the others.
- No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive. It only *needs* to occur once in the file. (It is often seen repeated when `.htaccess` files are edited by "the machine", not code "by hand".) For readability, this should be at the top of the file. However, if you have multiple `RewriteEngine` directives it's actually the *last* instance that wins and controls the entire file (which may not be intuitive). eg. If you put a `RewriteEngine Off` directive at the very end of the `.htaccess` file then... it's off for the whole file, despite any `RewriteEngine` directives you might have preceding this.

### Simplified (and "fixed"):

> 1. Redirect any non-www requests to the www variant;
> 2. Redirect any .com requests to the proper .org TLD;
> 3. Redirect any http to the proper https variant; 3

These 3 requirements are only satisfied if everything redirects to `www` + `.org` + HTTPS. ie. Everything must redirect to `https://www.example.org/` (the canonical URL).

So, your existing 3 rules can be reduced to a single rule, in order to satisfy your 3 requirements. ie. If the request is not for `https://www.example.org/` then redirect to `https://www.example.org/`.

```
RewriteEngine On

# If not the canonical host OR not HTTPS then redirect to HTTPS + canonical host
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80    
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

We don't need to reference `example.com` at all here, since we are only concerned whether it is *not* the canonical host.

And, since this is a WordPress site, this redirect must go before the WP front-controller, near the top of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: My dear @mrwhite - I cannot thank you enough for your help - this education on .htaccess is priceless to me!  I've done my best over the years to understand how it works and something was just niggling at the back of my mind that I wasn't doing this (particular function of redirects) as well as I could but I had no idea I was so way off base!  Thank you for taking the time to explain it and provide me with a solution, I'm sincerely deeply grateful (and blown away, actually).  If I had any plans to have children, I'd have one and name him/her after you.  Cheers!! <3

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to repeatedly write `RewriteEngine On`. Once is enough.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Although the 2nd rule doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Ahhh... doesn't it? I'd concluded (without testing) that it would establish a 301 redirect from any page on `example.com` to its counterpart on `example.org` (?)

Comment: Well, it's because the 1st rule redirects everything to `www.`. The 2nd rule matches against `example.com` only, so never matches. You could change the condition to match `www.example.com` (or just remove the `^`) - but now you have potentially 2 redirects, without reordering (and possibly tweaking) the rules.